# How to send a non-disturbing notification to users when they are in a game?

Tags: notification, games

This is for a mobile game for Texas poker.
We want to send a notification to our users when the special match they've signed for is about to begin.
But we don't want to disturb them too much when they are playing games in the poker room.

So what I could do to this notification for our users?

What about a little banner in the top of the screen to show them that the match is about to begin?

Comment: When you said playing games, do you mean the mobile game or the actual poker game? Notification is based on the user settings on the mobile phone, they have the option to set it to silent or alert with tone.

Comment: Well，I mean play mobile game.And we don't call the phone's notification system, we want to establish one in our game. Thank you. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels more like a UI question, but i will give it a try.

I think the notification will be more personal if it will be over the player avatar.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMcoWS.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for this interesting notification solution.But I am little worried about that would this notice over the player avatar too eye-catching?Will it disturb the player?

Comment: @NandoAma If the game is time based, i would show this notification to the player not at the exact moment the match was found, but when the player finished his turn and now he waits for the other players to make their turn. That way it will not disturb him.